# Why bootstrap tagsinput don't show full characters in tag and cross sign at end?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-tags-input

Here is am using tagsinput like this.

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' data-role='tagsinput' />
```

But when i add tag it shows tags properly if tag characters are less than or equal to 5. If character exceeds from 5 it does not show full tag text also no cross sign at end of tag. 
Here are screenshots

Entered 12345 and result:
[image]

Entered 123456 and result:[image]

Entered 1234567 and result:[image]

Entered 1234567890 and result:[image]

How can i show all text in tag and cross sign at end of tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this applying custom css on bootstrap tagsinput label

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput .label{
width: auto;
line-height:2;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check if your custom css is affecting `<span class="tag label label-info">world<span data-role="remove"></span></span>`

[please check here](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)